# Paypal: accept credit/debit card without paypal account

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway

To accept PayPal payments I see there are the following options for developer:

- Express Checkout
- PayPal Payments Standard
- PayPal Payments Advanced

Which of these options accept the credit/debit cards without the buyer has the PayPal account?

With Express Checkout is possible?

Comment: This is a great question that unfortunately is inappropriate for this SE site. A better one would be https://money.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

I used express checkout to accept payments even if the customer does not have a paypal account

You need to set **PayPal Account Optional** in your account/sandbox and set `SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole` in the `SetExpressCheckout` API call.

Answer (score 0):

**Express Checkout**: in which user needs to have a valid Paypal account.

PayPal Payments Standard and PayPal Payments Advanced are the two solutions offered by Paypal having different features, you can see a comparison of both [here](https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/compare-business-products).

Another method is **Direct Payment** (i.e. in which user can pay with credit cards directly without having any Paypal account). [Direct Payment API](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_dcc_hub-outside)

For this direct payment api you need to enable Website Payment Pro WPP , [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-pro/integration-guide/WPWebsitePaymentsPro/) you can get info about WPP.